# What is different between auth0 and IdentityServer?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identity, identityserver3, openid-connect, auth0

It seems these two provide both Authorization and Authentication.

Both use OpenID connect.

Answer (score 6):

IdentityServer is a framework for .NET that implements the OpenID Connect 1.0 & OAuth 2.0 specifications. With IdentityServer you configure everything yourself and own the code. User management features must be implemented yourself using a library such as ASP.NET Identity.

Auth0 is a paid for service that implements specifications such as OpenID Connect 1.0 & OAuth 2.0. They own the code and typically host it on their infrastructure. User management is provided out of the box.